# my square is not appearing as a square but taking up the length of the screen

Tags: html, css, square

I have recently tried to code a square in code ply but its not working.

```
HTML
<body>
<div class="red">
red
</body>


CSS
  .div { 
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid; 

 .red {
    background-color : red;
    }
```

it's taking up the whole screen in length

can some one help me?

just tried to do it in code ply again and it's not working at all. confused.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, just pay attention to the class you use in your `div` element. Here I fixed it for you.

```css
.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="red">
    red
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to close your `<div>` tag.

Change your html to:

```html
<body>
  <div class="red"> red </div>
</body>
```

Looking at your css, you have implied that there is a class called "div" and a class called "red". You have a `<div>` element with the class "red".

Change your css to:

```css
 div { 
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid; 
 }

.red {
    background-color : red;
}
```